# Checking if a key exists in a nested JSON element using Newtonsoft JSON and VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Using Newtonsoft Json with VB.NET I am trying to read some nested keys/elements within a block of JSON.

The JSON looks like this and is held in string `strSuppliedJSON`:

```
{
    "seller": {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Seller Name",
        "address1": "Seller address1",
        "country": "Seller country"
    },
    "buyer": {
        "id": 987,
        "name": "Buyer name",
        "address1": "Buyer address1",
        "country": "Buyer country"
    },
    "interview": {
        "call_id": 123,
        "vin": "The vin from the machine section",
        "call_date": "2019-12-31 23:59:59",
        "questions": ["Question1", "Question2", "Question3", "Question5", "Question5"],
        "triggers": [{
            "question": "Question1",
            "answers": ["Answer1", "Answer2"]
        }]
    }
}
```

Before reading the values I need to make sure some of the keys exist using `ContainsKey`.

The following works fine:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

' Create a dictionary
Dim dictionary As IDictionary(Of String, JToken) = JObject.Parse(strSuppliedJSON)

' Check if key exists - interview:triggers
If JObject.Parse(dictionary("interview").ToString()).ContainsKey("triggers") = False Then
    strAllChecksPassed = False
    result = "ERROR: JSON element not found: interview:triggers"
End If
```

However, when trying to check or read the `interview:triggers:question` things are falling over.

Using this, fails:

```
' Check if key exists - interview:triggers
If JObject.Parse(dictionary("interview").ToString()).ContainsKey("triggers") = False Then

    strAllChecksPassed = False
    result = "ERROR: JSON element not found: interview:triggers"

Else

    ' interview:triggers DOES exist, now check if the question exists - interview:triggers:question
    If JObject.Parse(dictionary("interview")("triggers").ToString()).ContainsKey("question") = False Then
        strAllChecksPassed = False
        result = "ERROR: JSON element not found: interview:triggers:question"
    End If

End If
```

The line that throws the error is:

`If JObject.Parse(dictionary("interview")("triggers").ToString()).ContainsKey("question") = False Then`

And the error is:

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1`

So I then tried to create a sub-dictionary of just the `interview` element.

I used this:

```
' Create a sub-dictionary of just the Interview element
Dim subDictionary As IDictionary(Of String, JToken) = JObject.Parse(dictionary("interview").ToString())
```

And if I then do `Response.Write(subDictionary)` I now see a smaller subset of my JSON, as expected:

```
{
    "call_id": 123,
    "vin": "The vin from the machine section",
    "call_date": "2019-12-31 23:59:59",
    "questions": ["Question1", "Question2", "Question3", "Question5", "Question5"],
    "triggers": [{
        "question": "Question1",
        "answers": ["Answer1", "Answer2"]
    }]
}
```

But then when trying to use my new `subDictionary` in the exact same way to see if the `question` key exists:

```
' Check if key exists - interview:triggers:question
If JObject.Parse(subDictionary("triggers").ToString()).ContainsKey("question") = False Then
    strAllChecksPassed = False
    result = "ERROR: JSON element not found: interview:triggers:question"
End If
```

I get the exact same error of:

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1`

Even though the line of code is identical!

How do I check if the nested key `interview:triggers:question` exists in my JSON, and what its value is?

Answer (score 2):

Look closely at `"triggers"` in the JSON: it's actually an *array of objects*, not an object. You need to index the array before you can access `"question"`.

Also note that every time you call `ToString`, you're reserializing something that you just deserialized with `Parse`. You don't need to do that. Parse the JSON once into a `JObject` and then reuse that object.

My VB-fu isn't great; I wrote this in C# and then converted it but the critical part is `Dim first As JToken = triggers(0)`. This gets the first array element, *on which* you can get the value associated with `"question"`.

```
        Dim suppliedObject As JObject = JObject.Parse(strSuppliedJSON)
        Dim interview As JToken = suppliedObject("interview")
        Dim triggers As JToken = If(interview IsNot Nothing, interview("triggers"), Nothing)

        If triggers Is Nothing Then
            strAllChecksPassed = False
            result = "ERROR: JSON element not found: interview:triggers"
        Else
            Dim first As JToken = triggers(0)
            Dim question As JToken = If(first IsNot Nothing, first("question"), Nothing)

            If question Is Nothing Then
                strAllChecksPassed = False
                result = "ERROR: JSON element not found: interview:triggers:question"
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

It fails because your path is not proper.

[] is an Array. You write out the name for single items (within {}), for arrays you write index (number).

And why are you parsing multiple times? Use what you already have, for example:

```
Dim JsonResp As JObject = JObject.Parse(<JSON>)

'Now there's multiple ways to do the same, here's one
If JsonResp ("interview")("triggers")(0)("question") Is Nothing Then
    strAllChecksPassed = False
    result = "ERROR: JSON element not found: interview:triggers:question"
End If
```